# Recursive function is able to print, but does not return the correct value

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm trying to make code for building parent and child nodes and searching data. These are rules:

1. Users must have different data.
2. Like a tree structure, user 1 becomes the parent node.
3. Parent node can search data from a child node.
4. Child node can search only its own data or more lower node's data.

And this is my code:

```
# row_data format : user id / parent id / number of data / data 1 ~ data n
row_data = ["1 0 3 1 2 3", "2 1 2 4 5", "3 1 2 6 7", "4 2 1 8", "5 0 2 9 10", "6 3 1 11", "7 6 1 12", "8 7 1 13",
        "9 8 2 14 15"]

# query "2 5": Does user 2 able to access Data 5? 
queries = ["2 5", "1 8"]
user_data = []


def search(uID, data):
    for dict in user_data:
        if data in dict["Data"]:
            if dict["USER_ID"] == uID:
                return True
            else:
                return parent_check(uID, dict["PARENT_ID"]) # [This is problem] Why isn't it return back?

def parent_check(uID, pID):
    for dict in user_data:
        if pID == dict["USER_ID"]:
            if uID == dict["USER_ID"]:
                return True # [This is problem] Why doesn't work "return"?

    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for input in row_data:
        input = input.split()

        input_data = {"USER_ID": input[0], "PARENT_ID": input[1], "NUMBER_OF_DATA": input[2], "Data": input[3:]}
        user_data.append(input_data)

    for query in queries:
        uID, data = query.split()
        print(search(uID, data))
```

I tried to solve this using the dictionary data type.

My code does not show an error, but it doesn't show the desired result either. When I try printing using `print("search complete")` in the `return true` area of `parent_check()`, it works perfectly. However, the return from the recursive call does not work. The return shows as none.

When I run my code the output should be true / true, but I'm getting true / false instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recursive function all code paths need a `return` statement. Try this:

```
def parent_check(uID, pID):
    for dict in user_data:
        if pID == dict["USER_ID"]:
            if uID == dict["USER_ID"]:
                return True 
            else:
                return parent_check(uID, dict["PARENT_ID"]) 
    return False
```

Code added by me:

```
else:
    return parent_check(uID, dict["PARENT_ID"])
```

Output:

```
True
True
```